# Setting up simple Website with apache2

Tags: server, windows, apache2, firefox

I'm relatively new to ubuntu and coding in general and have found this site to be rather helpful so thought I'd ask my question here.

I'm running a fresh install of the ubuntu app from the windows 10 microsoft store and was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-q8Jj4aAWYw) on how to setup a quick website. I installed apache2 and run firefox through ubuntu with Xming to give me the GUI but everytime I check localhost in firefox I get that the server was not found.

basically from the fresh install I did

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

according to the tutorial from that I should be able to go to localhost from firefox and see the sample webpage but its not working. Does this have something to do with the fact that I'm running ubuntu on windows instead of like they did in the tutorial video? Also when I run the various checks that he does in the tutorial like `netstat -a | more` it just shows up as basically blank which I assume means I don't have the server setup.

How can I get just the sample webpage to load properly into localhost?

Comment: Have you started the Apache? If not use `service apache2 start` (might need sudo privileges)

Comment: That seems to have done it and I can load the default page but still nothing is showing up from the netstat -a | more command.

Comment: what do you get after `netstat -a`?

Answer (score 0):

After installing a new program usually you need to run it.
Follow [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/star-stop-restart-apache2-webserver/) tutorial on Apache server.